# AWS SNS and load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, distributed-system

I'm currently facing a problem when thinking about a event driven arch using SNS to decouple some applications.

Imagine a SNS Topic, and I have application A producing messages to it and application B will listen and consume messages from this topic.

I want to consume the messages only once if I attach one more instance to application B so shall I use Load balancer for the same or not ?
I will subscribe the topic using load balancer URL and distribute the messages between the instances of application B.

Comment: Make an SQS subscription to SNS topic and make applications read messages from SQS. No matter how many instances you will have, only 1 instance can read the message at the same time. If you have some kind of a problem that message is read by multiple instances you can implement a logic in the application that stores messageId or receiptHandle in the database

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.